# Detect if media scanner running on Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to detect whether MediaScanner is running now or not .

for example if mediascanner is running,Thread will sleep for 200 milis.
thanks.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/9647478/614807

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code.

```
 public static boolean isMediaScannerScanning(ContentResolver cr) {
        boolean result = false;
        Cursor cursor = query(cr, MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri(),
               new String [] {MediaStore.MEDIA_SCANNER_VOLUME},
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                result = "external".equals(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }    
        return result;
    }
```

It is copied from  ImageManager.java of AOSP.